# Schedule Task ECS Fargate at interval time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a doubt. I try to use ECS Schedule Task.

Mi first impression is the next... I can't say to Schedule task please run N task for two hours and after that stop them. In the options I have rate or cron but none of that options can't help me because the goal of them is run N task every N (minutes,hours,days, etc) and when the main proccess of the task it's finished, stop.

**But I want to run N task for a specific time.** Because mi task is an API but I need the API only in specific interval of time.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or really the task schedules are not the best solution to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

- I think you can achieve this using step function and aws lambda with boto3 client.
- Stepfunctions have wait until specific time future for your usecase.